# Apply money to money

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a question about the meaning of the phrase "*apply to*" in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski#Court_proceedings):

> The auctioneer paid the cost and kept up to 10% of the sale price, and the rest of the proceeds must be ***applied to*** the $15 million in restitution that Burrell ordered Kaczynski to pay his victims.

The usage in the wiki article has the pattern "*apply one kind of money to another kind of money*", which I don't quite understand.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Kaczynsky was ordered to pay $15 mn to his victims (in restitution). The sale of his belongings generated some revenue. This revenue will be used to pay money to his victims, under this $15 mn obligation.

Comment: @CopperKettle  Is there a dictionary definition of "*apply*" that fits this usage?

Comment: I've got no idea.

Comment: Yes, there is a dictionary definition for the same. Check the (2) definition for apply in http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apply

Comment: Apply : "To put to or adapt for a special use: applies all her money to her mortgage."

Comment: @VarunKN  So, the original is poorly written?

Comment: No, I'm just giving you the definition of 'apply' in this context. Your question is 100% valid. There's nothing wrong with it. I didn't want to post a link as the answer, ergo the comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

> The usage in the wiki article has the pattern "apply one kind of money to another kind of money",

The money is not being applied to another kind of money, it is being applied to a debt. An obligation.

[Here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apply) is an alternate definition of 'Apply':

> To put to use

Substituting, we get the sentence

> The auctioneer paid the cost and kept up to 10% of the sale price, and the rest of the proceeds must be *put to use* to the $15 million in restitution that Burrell ordered Kaczynski to pay his victims.

How do you put money to use? By buying things, or paying off debts. So, this money is being *put to use* to pay off a debt. Here is a slight paraphrasing

> The auctioneer paid the cost and kept up to 10% of the sale price, and the rest of the proceeds must be *put to use **to pay off*** the $15 million in restitution that Burrell ordered Kaczynski to pay his victims.

Comment: Would this rewrite of the original: "... *the rest of the proceeds must be* ***applied to the payment of*** *the $15 million in restitution*..." , be better?

Comment: @meatie That one or the original both sound pretty natural and clear to me. Now that I look at it, I think both of my rewrites would sound strange out loud.